# Appendices in Table of Content (TOC): remove indentation

Tags: table-of-contents, indentation, appendices

I'm writing my thesis, and I need to include my appendices in the table of contents (TOC). So, I wrote some code in latex and I got the following result:

[image: appendices_toc_issue]

The problem is that I don't want my appendices titles have indentation. I need them to be aligned with the Appendice title (ANEXOS) and the other chapters, as you can see in the previous figure. Any advice? Thank you!

This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}

\begin{document}
%
\tableofcontents
%
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{Objectives}

\chapter{Chapter 1}
\section{Theory}
%
% Appendix
\renewcommand{\appendixpagename}{Anexos}
\renewcommand{\appendixtocname}{\textbf{ANEXOS}}
\renewcommand{\appendixname}{Anexo}
%
\begin{appendices}
%
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}}
\makeatletter
\addtocontents{toc}{
    \begingroup
    \let\protect\l@chapter\protect\l@section
    \let\protect\l@section\protect\l@subsection
}
%
\chapter{Algorithms 1}
\section{RMA}
\chapter{Algorithms 2}
\section{FDBP}
%
\addtocontents{toc}{\endgroup}
\end{appendices}
%
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of just copying the ToC handling of sections/subsections into those of chapters/sections, redefine them appropriately with the correct spacing/indentation:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Introduction}
\section{Objectives}

\chapter{Chapter 1}
\section{Theory}

% Appendix
\renewcommand{\appendixpagename}{Anexos}
\renewcommand{\appendixtocname}{\textbf{ANEXOS}}
\renewcommand{\appendixname}{Anexo}

\begin{appendices}

%\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}}

\makeatletter
\addtocontents{toc}{%
  \begingroup
  % Default definitions of \l@section and \l@subsection in book.cls
  % https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/book.cls?view=co
  % \newcommand*\l@section{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{2.3em}}
  % \newcommand*\l@subsection{\@dottedtocline{2}{3.8em}{3.2em}}
  \protect\renewcommand{\protect\l@chapter}{\protect\@dottedtocline{1}{0pt}{2.3em}}%
  \protect\renewcommand{\protect\l@section}{\protect\@dottedtocline{2}{2.3em}{3.2em}}%
}

\chapter{Algorithms 1}
\section{Special algorithms}

\chapter{Algorithms 2}
\addtocontents{toc}{\endgroup}
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This answer almost works, but I don't want sections to appear in the TOC, i.e . *A.1 Special algorithms*, only chapters appear in the TOC. How could I do that? Thanks.

Comment: @LuisD.: You'll note that I commented out setting the `tocdepth` counter to `1`. If you uncomment that, anything higher than a sectional unit level of 1 won't appear in the ToC (which includes the newly-defined `\section` at level 2).

Comment: It works! I uncommented that line. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the `titletoc` option when you load `appendix` and remove the code after `\begin{appendix}`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[toc, page]{appendix}%

\begin{document}
%
\tableofcontents
%
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{Objectives}

\chapter{Chapter 1}
\section{Theory}
%
% Appendix
\renewcommand{\appendixpagename}{Anexos}
\renewcommand{\appendixtocname}{\textbf{ANEXOS}}
\renewcommand{\appendixname}{Anexo}
%
\begin{appendices}
\chapter{Algorithms 1}
\chapter{Algorithms 2}
\end{appendices}
%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response. Is there any way to show only "A Algorithms 1" instead of "Anexo A Algorithms 1"? I need that format. Regards.

Comment: @LuisD.: It seems I misunderstood part of your requirements. You just  have to remove the `titletoc` option. I'll fix my answer in a moment.

Comment: that is better, but the chapter titles of the appendices are not in **bold case**, they are in normal font, as I showed in the figure I attached. I also forgot to include sections in appendices (I'll add them in a moment), and it's necessary that only the chapters appear in the TOC. Your code output both, chapters and sections, in the TOC. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This does what you want, including only Appendix chapters in the ToC (no sections there).

```
% appendixprob.tex  SE 572664

\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}%

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Introduction}
\section{Objectives}

\chapter{Chapter 1}
\section{Theory}

% Change the Appendix name
\renewcommand{\appendixpagename}{Anexos}
\renewcommand{\appendixtocname}{\textbf{ANEXOS}}
\renewcommand{\appendixname}{Anexo}

\begin{appendices}
%%%% only appendix chapters in the ToC
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}}
\chapter{Algorithms 1}
\section{First section}
\chapter{Algorithms 2}
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

[image]